# Internet Explorer WebDriver Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, nullpointerexception, webdriver

I am trying to run a test using the cross browser tool (using FF, Chrome and IE). FF and Chrome work fine, but i can't get Internet Explorer to work, it keeps giving me a null pointer exception (images included). So far I have tried using IE 11 backing up to 10 and now I have backed up to 9 but it doesn't seem to be a compatibility issue. I have also tried updating my POM file to multiple versions (2.42, 2.42.2, 2.43, 2.432, 2.44 and 2.45) Version 2.45 runs both Chrome and Firefox. I have included my code in the attachment. I am out of ideas an not sure what else to do. The Image below shows my code which I believe is correct for the set up before my test. I am calling the correct file path and have instantiated the driver to IE.    I can't pose an Image because this is my first question on here and it won't let me post until my repuation is at a 10. I have tried to be as descriptive as possible and any help would be appreciated.

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TR3F.png)

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OnHk.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of the `InternetExplorer` in the pom file is mentioned as **InternetExplorer** whereas while instantiating you are using **ie**. Replace **ie** with **InternetExplorer** in java file or vice versa